# NetSuite SuiteTalk REST Web Services - Invalid Login Attempt - Sandbox Account ID vs. Account ID in URL

Tags: rest, api, postman, netsuite, suitetalk

I'm attempting to use Netsuite Suite Talk REST Web Services (Beta, 2019.2 release) and have followed Netsuite's setup instructions (integration, token, downloaded Postman collection, etc). I keep getting a 401 error but found on stack overflow [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447622/netsuite-suitetalk-rest-web-services-invalid-login-attempt) referencing how Sandbox account id's in a URL have a dash while the account ID itself has an underscore.

**Example:**

Account ID in URL is

```
https://1234567-sb1.app.netsuite.com/
```

While the Account ID is:

```
1234567_sb1
```

I have tried editing my account ID from a dash to an underscore within the environment, that didn't work. Then I tried editing my account ID in the OAuth screen, that didn't work. Then I tried editing the GET example request and that didn't work either. When I add the account ID with underscore in the "Realm" field under authorization that produces a 500 Error.

Where in Postman would I go to make this change?